# Visual Studio Asp.Net development: Website -> Asp.net configuration doesnt exist

Tags: asp.net

I am trying to make a website that involves membership and I want to change roles and Stuff so i hava done some research and found i can manage roles and other stuff from Website -> Asp.net configuration section 
But Asp.net config section doesnt exist I also couldnt create ASPNETDB.MDF cuz aspnet_regsql couldnt connect to sql servers I tried everything to fix these two errors but still nothing I am working for nearly 10 days on this topic

Hope You can help me

Comment: Sry for 2 questions at the same time I would still be pleased if You answer only 1

Answer (score 0):

This Option has been removed from Visual Studio 2015.
To access ASP.NET website configuration tool check this tutorial :
 https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-t_bJW80NQQ